# Ethernet drop out

Tags: ethernet

I've just installed Raspbian.

Loaded it up with ethernet (led is on).

Everything went smooth for about an hour.

Left it while programming in a text file.

Then the internet went down. tried to ping 8.8.8.8, it says

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

This will go back to normal IF i reboot Raspberry Pi

Power Cable is 5V 1A

Comment: Are you 100% that rebooting the raspberry pi fixed it? Cause I am having problems with internet that is sometimes going down all of the sudden. (with everything) and I once restarted and I had internet again but it wasn't because I restarted it. It was just coincidental.

Comment: Try to disconnect usb devices. Set up a ssh access and see if there's any difference.

Comment: Unusually that the internet goes like that. Can you still ping other devices on the LAN, e.g. the router?

Answer (score 1):

I've never noticed the ethernet drop out and I've had it on most of the time for months.  But...

The next time this happens, try `service networking restart`.  If that doesn't work, try in order:

```
service networking stop
dhclient -r
ifconfig eth0 up
dhclient eth0
```

If that works, leave a comment and I can give you a suggestion for keeping the interface up.

Comment: i've tried this. still the same error

Comment: okay, looks like when ethernet drop out, i had to 
    `sudo /etc/init.d/networking reload` all the time!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you have 5V 1A ? I had the same issue, I had a power cable saying 5V 1A but it just got 5V 0.5A.
Try a different power supply and report again :)

Comment: Confirm. am using android samsung charger.

Comment: Is the problem solved, or does this happen all over again ?

Comment: yeap. it happened again after my last reboot. connection lasts around two hours before it dropped.
i tried adding
`servername 8.8.8.8`
in /etc/resolve.conf
still, no difference.